# How to make a databasevalue show up red if it's below zero?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Right, so I've been working on a website where all income is displayed and difference in percent is calculated. This data, including the percentages are set using MySQLI and are json encoded.

On the main page I set all the values in a span, which is bound to the span ID.
EXAMPLE:

```
DATAQUERIES SIDE:
<?php
$data("database_data") = getdata("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE something")

echo json_encode($data);
?>



WEBSITE SIDE
$(document).ready(function() {
     var interv = setInterval(getnumber, 10000);

function getnumber(){
     $.get( "data.php", function( data ) {
     var d=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          $('#span_id').html(d['database_data']);
     }); 
  });
};

HTML WEBSITE SIDE
//If the code has ran through, it will provide the following. Within this 
//"database data" functions as example
<span id="span_id">'database data'</span>
```

The value that will be added to the span is supposed to be RED when the value is below zero, blue when the value IS zero and green when the value is above zero.

The provided code above is used throughout a lot of websites and is not supposed to be altered, just fyi.

Comment: Before outputting `database data` do a check on it. If `< 0` add a class to the element.. or i guess it probably could be done with jquery as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen for changes on "span_id", then read in the contents of the span and set a style based on the contents:

```
$('span_id').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  var text = $('span_id').text();
  if (text.contains("blah")) {
    // I don't know your text format or how to check it
    $('span_id').attr('color','red')
  }
});
```